# API for liveness check

Tags: face-recognition

I'm looking for an API or solution to verify the liveness of an image or a video.
E.g. To make sure that whatever the web camera sees, is a live person and not an image or a video on someone's phone, held in front of a webcam.

Looked at Azure and AWS API but nothing like that is available. Gazed at OpenCV but it seems it will require a lot of training.

Does anyone have any experience with the topic they can share?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have full control on the hardware, that's next to impossible to do based only on the webcam input. Do share with us if you find a solution though.

It is almost impossible because virtual cameras can be fed real video that was previously filmed by that same camera, so they'd be digitally undistinguishable. You might not be able to infer the liveness unless there is a serious real-life mismatch (say, sunlight at a time when there is supposed to be none).